Products Carousel not shifting
I have created a product carousel using Javascript, the idea is i have a row of 10 products and one product is focused means the product i click on it zooms in and show more information about it and it should be in the middle. now when i click on unfocused product whether right or left am expecting that all products shifts until the one i cliked takes the middle position here is the carousel photo:

and this is the Js code:
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    const carousel = $('.carousel-custom');
    const items = $('.carousel-item');
    let focusedIndex = 5; // Start with the fourth item focused

// Function to center the focused item
function centerItem(index) {
    const item = $(items[index]);
    const carouselWidth = carousel.width();
    const itemWidth = item.outerWidth(true);
    
    // Calculate the scroll position to center the item
    const scrollPosition = 135;
    // Debugging output
    console.log('Focused Index:', index);
    console.log('Item Position:', item.position().left);
    console.log('Carousel Width:', carouselWidth);
    console.log('Item Width:', itemWidth);
    console.log('Scroll Position:', scrollPosition);

    // Ensure scroll position is not negative or out of bounds
    if (scrollPosition < 0) {
        carousel.animate({ scrollLeft: 0 }, 300);
    } else if (scrollPosition + carouselWidth > carousel[0].scrollWidth) {
        carousel.animate({ scrollLeft: carousel[0].scrollWidth - carouselWidth }, 300);
    } else {
        // Animate the scroll to the calculated position
        carousel.animate({ scrollLeft: scrollPosition }, 300);
    }

    
    
}

// Function to set the focus on an item by index
function setFocus(index) {
    // Remove focused class from all items
    items.removeClass('focused');
    // Add focused class to the specified item
    $(items[index]).addClass('focused');
    // Center the focused item
    centerItem(index);
}

// Function to trigger a click on the focused item
function triggerClick(index) {
    items.eq(index).trigger('click');
}

// Set initial focus on the third item and trigger a click
setFocus(focusedIndex);
triggerClick(focusedIndex); // This simulates a click on the third item

// Click event for carousel items
items.on('click', function() {
    const clickedIndex = $(this).index();
    console.log('Clicked Index:', clickedIndex); // Debugging output
    setFocus(clickedIndex); // Focus on clicked item
});

});

The issue is the products are not shifting when i click on one they stay in the same place.

You're currently using a static or hardcoded value for scrollPosition. Instead, you should calculate it based on the clicked item's position relative to the carousel and its width. This will ensure the clicked item is centered correctly.
const scrollPosition = itemOffset - (carouselWidth / 2) + (itemWidth / 2);

Please give it a try and let me know if it works

i get an error in the console "itemOffset is not defined", i thought its predefined in Js. do you mean the item position ?
